# FullCalendar dayClick functionality

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-events

I am fairly new to the FullCalendar, but totally love it's functionality.
I am trying to use the `dayClick` function. Perhaps someone can guide me in the right direction.

I currently have this:

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            var titleNew = prompt('Event Title:');
            var thedate1 = formatDate(date);
            
            $.ajax({
                url: "classes/class.Post.php?a=dayClickCalendarEvent",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 
                      title: titleNew,
                      start: thedate1,
                      end: thedate1
                },
                success: function (data, response, event, date) {

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', titleNew);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Oops! Something didn't work");
                }
            });
        },
```

My problem is that I can't get the event to RENDER to the calendar no matter what.
Am I missing something? I am using the `calEvent`, where I found it on another Stack Overflow post.

Here is my format code:

```
function formatDate(date1) {
   return date1.getFullYear() +'-'
         + (date1.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '')
         + (date1.getMonth()+1) +'-'
         + (date1.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') 
         + date1.getDate() +' '
         + (date1.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '')
         + date1.getHours() +':'
         + (date1.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '')
         + date1.getMinutes();
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think formatDate may be undefined. Do you have it in scope? I think you may need to use $.fullCalendar.formatDate.

Comment: My format doesnt affect any other event its weird.

Here is my format code.
function formatDate(date1) {
      return date1.getFullYear() +'-'+
     (date1.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '') + (date1.getMonth()+1) +'-'+
     (date1.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date1.getDate() +' '+
     (date1.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date1.getHours() +':'+
     (date1.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date1.getMinutes();
    }

Answer (score 1):

Hey I thank you for your responses, I was able to use this code and it responds great!

```
     dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
           titleNew = prompt('Event Title:');
           var thedate1 = formatDate(date);

            $.ajax({
                url: "classes/class.Post.php?a=dayClickCalendarEvent",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 
                      title: titleNew,
                      start: thedate1,
                      end: thedate1
                },
                success: function (data, response, event, date) {
                    //alert("success here");
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: titleNew,
                        start: thedate1,
                        end: thedate1
                    }, true);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Oops! Something didn't work");
                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: You know the `thedate1` can just be a date object (e.g. `thedate1 = new Date();`. But I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Yeah potentially, but you still need to format the date, which I used a custom function for into a capable MySQL specific date (ie: 2010-08-02 23:30). Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: How did you solve this, I constantly have $("#calendar").fullcalendar is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this statement `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', titleNew);`

`titleNew` is a string, and the `renderEvent` function takes a calEvent object.

From the FullCalendar Documentation:

> event must be an Event Object with a title and start at the very least.
>   Normally, the event will disappear once the calendar refetches its event sources (example: when prev/next is clicked). However, specifying stick as true will cause the event to be permanently fixed to the calendar.

I'm curious why you are using an Ajax call though, it doesn't seem like you are doing anything with it.

Comment: If I use something like, $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, stick); it still causes problems. 

In my other code when i'm updating an event I use:
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event, stick);

and it works great. But only when i'm adding it doesn't seem to want to add. 

Inside the AJAX call i'm using that to add it to a database under the URL calling a switch statement with my data variables. Is this a bad practice?

Comment: I'm sure you have already checked, but does the 'success' event get fired? Have you tried putting an alert in there? What are you getting from the server? I see that you are calling for json, but you aren't using it. Also - the signature seems wrong to me, it should be success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest).  I don't know what the 'date' member is.